# To retrieve all the asp buttons which are disabled and apply css

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I have asp.net application In IE 9 some asp.net  buttons are disabled and are appearing as grayed out . But in IE 11 the buttons are disabled but are not grayed out.Is there any way to get all the asp.net buttons on that page and apply gray css to them . Some buttons are inside grid and are dynamic so Id fetching won't work . So Please help.
I am planning to put a document. ready and catch all the button there and check if the disabled attribute is tru then apply a particular css . Please provide the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Javascript.It can be easily achieved by using **css selector** `:disabled`.Which will apply it to all disabled buttons.

```css
input[type=button]:disabled,

button:disabled {

  background: grey;

  color: white;

}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Disabled button one" disabled>
<br>
<button disabled>Disabled button two</button>
<br>

<input type="button" value="Enabled button one">
<br>
<button>Enabled button two</button>
```